# Cucumber test results always return 0 if run from Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber

**EDIT (2018-01-24):**
Since none of the comments are working, I have updated the post to include the present state and include more details. If anyone can have a fresh look, please go ahead.

---

When running `mvn clean test`, the test results for Cucumber are always 0. When a step fails, the result is always BUILD SUCCESS.

**Maven Results:**

[image: mvn_clean_test]

**Directory Structure:**

[image: dir_struc]

**pom.xml:**

```
<project>
  [...]
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Core Dependencies -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
        <ngwebdriver.version>1.0</ngwebdriver.version>
        <selenium.version>3.8.1</selenium.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paulhammant/ngwebdriver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paulhammant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ngwebdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${ngwebdriver.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Runner:**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features", tags = { "~@ignore" }, glue = "stepdefs", plugin = {
        "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports/test-report", "json:target/cucumber-reports/test-report.json",
        "junit:target/cucumber-reports/test-report.xml" }, snippets = SnippetType.UNDERSCORE, monochrome = true, dryRun = false)

public class MainRunner {

}
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out `<exclude>**/*Runner.java</exclude>`?

Comment: Hi, the test did not execute after commenting it out.

Comment: What are the names of the classes containing your test methods? You might need to include them explicitly if they don't match the [patterns which are automatically included.](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

Comment: HI, thank you for that hint. I have added a screenshot of the packages/classes. If you could kindly post a snippet of how the pom.xml needs to be modified, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you please verify if the glue is pointing to the correct step file and also try to add specific tags for tests

Comment: @zealvault Currently I only have 1 step definition class (screenshot) and 1 hook where my Before and After are. I am building the Maven structure so this test suite only has 1 feature and 1 stepdef with 6 steps. The test is executing and opens the browser, just that the Test report is not reflected correctly.

Comment: You could either rename your stepdefs file(s) to start or end with `Test`, or you could add `<include>**/CalculateNetIncomeSteps.java</include>`. Alternatively, `**/stepdefs/*` might do the job.

Comment: Hi, renaming the stepdefs (both hook and steps) to end in "Test" did not reflect changes. If anyone can review the pom that'd be great. I just took it from a tutorial video, it wasn't explained why an `<exclude>` tag is inside an `<includes>` tag.

Comment: Rename the runner class name from MainRunner  to TestRunner or RunnerTest(runner class name should start or end with Test).

Comment: Renaming the runner class to end in Test doesn't solve it either. It also shouldn't matter as it is also defined in the `<includes>` tag anyway. The test executes, I don't understand why it's not reflecting in the Test results in the console.

Comment: Try removing the Maven Surefire plugin and specify test as scope of Cucumber JUnit dependency like :  <dependency>
     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.5</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: Removing the surefire plugin from the pom did not execute the test. All of my cucumber related dependencies have a <scope> of test.

Comment: I have modified the post. Thanks so far to everyone giving their suggestions.

Comment: @silver What do you use `TestNG` for?

Comment: Hi Rafal, just for assertions, I prefer it over JUnit.

Comment: @silver Give me some time. I'll try to recreate your framework, dependencies etc to find possible issues.
If you happen to fix it on your own, let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

Problems are caused by `TestNG` `Assert`. Looks like Maven reads only `JUnit` Asserts.

When I switched my `JUnit` Asserts to `TestNG` I was able to recreate your issue.

[image: Recreated problem]

Comment: Hi Rafal, thank you for looking into this. I'm at work but I should be able to try this solution later. Will get back to you after. :)

Comment: Sorry it took a while but this works! I removed cucumber-testng from the pom.xml and changed all assertions to JUnit. That was interesting to know. :) Unfortunately, this probably means I can't use Cucumber + TestNG + Maven. I do like TestNG because it handles data-driven testing better.

Comment: @silver There are some articles, how to integrate TestNG and Cucumber together. Maybe there is still a solution :)
Glad I could help. Happy coding!

Comment: I have found out it is possible to use Cucumber + TestNG + Maven. You have to remove cucumber-junit and use cucumber-testng in pom.xml instead. Then extend runner class with `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests`.